# Submit more than one form in Javascript/ajax or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

This is what I am trying to do I have 3 forms in one page, i need to have to because one form is open in modal dialog, I wish to submit all 3 forms when the user click in a single button, also I would like a ajax implementation of sucess en error function in the form submit

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

var firstFormData = $("#form1").serialize();
var secondFormData = $("#form2").serialize();
var thirdFormData = $("#form3").serialize();


$.post(
    URL: test.php             
    firstFormData + secondFormData + thirdFormData
); 
</script>

<form id="form1">
<input type="text" name="one"></input>
</form>

<form id="form2">
<input type="text" name="two"></input>
</form>

<form id="form3">
<input type="text" name="three"></input>
</form>

<button>submit here</button>
<?php 

echo $_POST['one']; 
echo $_POST['two']; 
echo $_POST['three']; 

?>
```

Comment: First of all, you should add a onClick handler for the submit button. Then, you can just concatenate serialization results from all forms and make an AJAX request. This doesn't differ from the usual AJAX request with any custom data.

Comment: $.post accepts a data parameter. You can build it however you want. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Was your problem solved? If so, you should close this question by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just do the following:

```
var combinedFormData = $("#form1,#form2,#form3").serialize();
```

This will serialize all three forms into one query string. Just make sure the input names don't overlap.

A complete implementation would look like this:

```
<?php
      // PHP Code to return the HTML to be inserted in the #result div
      // Just for demonstration purposes.
      if (count($_POST) > 0) {
            echo "<p>You successfully posted:</p><ul>";
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
                    echo "<li>$key: $val</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            exit;
      }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" name="one">
    </form>

    <form id="form2">
        <input type="text" name="two">
    </form>

    <form id="form3">
        <input type="text" name="three">
    </form>

    <button id="sendforms">Submit forms</button>

    <div id="result"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#sendforms").click(function() {
                   var combinedFormData = $("#form1,#form2,#form3").serialize();
                 $.post(
                        "test.php",
                        combinedFormData
                 ).done(function(data) {
                        alert("Successfully submitted!");
                        $("#result").html(data);
                 }).fail(function () {
                          alert("Error submitting forms!");
                 })
          });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please note that the PHP code is just for illustration and testing. You should neither implement your form handling like this, nor put it in the same file like your form. It's just all bad style :-)

Here is a working jsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/kLa1pd6p/

Comment: It's fine but when I retrive in the php vars echo $_POST['one'];
  echo $_POST['two'];
  echo $_POST['three']; no value is posted I am submitting the the same test.php file

Comment: Of course it doesn't show anything. You are doing an asynchronous $.post there. That means the page is never reloaded, thus your PHP script is never executed again (in the browser). The request calls a second version of the test.php, but you won't see the result in the browser.

Comment: It can be on the same page, but you should have it return something for the script to display back to the user. You will get the result from the server in the callback. I will edit my answer, hold on...

Comment: You can [try this](http://js.do/code/fadhilmakunga) , hope it will help

Comment: The answer now includes the necessary PHP code to return some HTML data that is then put in the result-div in the .done callback. This should give you the idea... however, put the form processing in a different file to keep things clean.

Comment: still not getting any data

Comment: It works fine for me. Let me combine all the code in one block for you to copy it over...

Comment: I included a complete version of the test.php file that works if you use it as is.

Comment: Thanks for the great example, the php part I only needed to check if it was alredy posted to execute the php very usefull, `if (count($_POST) > 0) { //code here }`

Answer (score 1):

This also should work for you :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$("#sub").on("click mousedown touchstart", function (){
var firstFormData = $("#form1").serialize();
var secondFormData = $("#form2").serialize();
var thirdFormData = $("#form3").serialize();

    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {
                one: firstFormData,
                two: secondFormData,
                three: thirdFormData
              },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); 

});    

</script>
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="one"></input>
</form>

<form id="form2">
  <input type="text" name="two"></input>
</form>

<form id="form3">
  <input type="text" name="three"></input>
</form>

<button id="sub">submit here</button>

<?php 

  echo $_POST['one'];
  echo $_POST['two'];
  echo $_POST['three'];
?>
```

Comment: Not working, also I need a implementation of sucess and error funciton

Comment: I tested my file is test.php I am submiting to the same file but when I retrive the vars , no data sent
echo $_POST['one'];
  echo $_POST['two'];
  echo $_POST['three'];

Answer (score 1):

Your almost done with your implementation. To concatenate the forms, you should use `&`.

```
var firstFormData = $("#form1").serialize();
var secondFormData = $("#form2").serialize();
var thirdFormData = $("#form3").serialize();

$.post('test.php', firstFormData + "&" + secondFormData + "&" + thirdFormData)
    .done(function(data) {
        // success function
    }).fail(function() {
        // fail function
    });
```

to add an event handler to the button, you could add an id an attach an event handler

```
<button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
```

and the event handler

```
$('#submit-btn').on('click', function() {
    // do the ajax call
    var data = $('#form1,#form2,#form3');
    $.post('test.php', data).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: How do I call it when user click in the button?

Comment: Give the button an id or class and add an event handler - I add an example

Comment: why 2 functions? this file is the test.php I am submiting to the same file where the code is written but it's not working yet

Comment: what do you mean with two functions? the latest code snippet is the only you need to do the request - the other was just an other example how you could do it